# Discord.js Discord API Error unknow message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

i use Discord.js V12.0.2, i try to block discord invite links,
i use this code

```
client.on('message', (message) => { 
  if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/'||'discordapp.com/invite/')) { 
    message.delete()
      .then(message.channel.send('**Invite links are not permitted on this server**'))
  }
})
```

and i get this Error

```
DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the discord API, but there is a significant bug in your code, that might produce your error.

The thing is that

```js
'discord.gg/' || 'discordapp.com/invite/'
```

is equal to `true`. Because a non-empty string is a truthy value and having `true || true` results in `true`. What is the result if you refactor your code to the following:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => { 
  const content = message.content;
  if (content.includes('discord.gg/') || content.includes('discordapp.com/invite/')) { 
    message
      .delete()
      .then(message.channel.send('**Invite links are not permitted on this server**'))
  }
})
```

Comment: unfortunately still the same mistake